# Create and Copy subfolder to another directory using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, directory, copy, subdirectory

I need to match if a parent folder exists in one directory to another => if yes, then I need to copy only one-subfolder from the parent folder and all the contents of it, then => create that sub-folder under the parent folder in another directory, in loop.

So far, I have been able to match and create parent folder and sub-folder in another directory but did not have any success in copying the contents of it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub CreateFolders()

'Declare variables for the main folder and subfolder name
Dim mainFolder As String
Dim subFolder As String
Dim subfolders As Range

'Set the main folder path
mainFolder = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"

'Loop through each row in the worksheet
For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    'Get the main folder name from first cell of the current row
    mainFolder = mainFolder & ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value
    'Check if the main folder does not exist
    If Len(Dir(mainFolder, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        'Create the main folder
        MkDir mainFolder
    End If

    'Get the range of subfolder names from the rest of the cells in the current row
    Set subfolders = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2), _
                ActiveSheet.Cells(i, ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count))

    'Loop through the subfolder names
    For Each cell In subfolders
        'Create subfolder name if the cell has value
        If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
            subFolder = cell.Value
            'Check if the subfolder does not exist
            If Len(Dir(mainFolder & "\" & subFolder, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
                'Create the subfolder
                MkDir mainFolder & "\" & subFolder
            End If
        End If
    Next cell

    'Reset main folder path
    mainFolder = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Please provide a sample to illustrate what "one directory" and "another directory" refer to in your post.

Comment: Don't you have headers (`For i = 1 To...`)? There is only one main folder in your code (`ThisWorkbook.Path`). Where is the other one? Which one is the source? Instead of repeatedly modifying `mainFolder` in the loop, you should use another variable e.g. `currentFolder = mainFolder & ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value`.

Comment: @VBasic2008 you are probably right, my above code is flawed  - as I am relatively new to VB. Could you please help me out?

Comment: No problem but you need to share more information: the paths of the subfolders (only destination, if `ThisWorkbook.Path` is the source path), the name of the worksheet (`ActiveSheet` could be anywhere) and if it's in `ThisWorkbook`, the first row of data, and what to do when a folder already exists (copy anyway and overwrite or skip).

Answer (score 0):

I would use the FileSystemObject in VBA to copy the contents of the subfolders.  Call below sub in your code.

```
Sub CopyAll(fromFolder As String, toFolder As String)
    Dim FSO As Object
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    If FSO.FolderExists(fromFolder) Then
        FSO.GetFolder(toFolder).Copy toFolder
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @vbakim, however, I believe we will need to define the source path to copy and destination path to paste the folder.

I need to copy a subfolder from one location and paste it another location, if missing - the above code is not filling that purpose.